# Swift 4. Could you suggest how to play video after returning to the app?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a video on the phone view AVPlayer, but if press home button the application collapses – video automatically stops and if open the app again – the app is on pause. With the AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground I demand my view and try to continue the video playback, but it continues being paused. After transition in other view and returning back - video continues to play.
Could you suggest how to play video after returning to the app?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

var player: AVPlayer?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playVideo()
}

public func test()
{
    print("1111")
    if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing
    {
        print("playing") // not print
    }
    else if player?.timeControlStatus == .paused
    {
        player?.play()
        print("paused") // not print
    }
}

private func playVideo()
{
    let file1 : String = "portable.mp4";

    let file = file1.components(separatedBy: ".")
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file[0], ofType:file[1]) else {
        debugPrint( "\(file.joined(separator: ".")) not found")
        return
    }
    player = nil
    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    player?.isMuted = false
    player?.volume = 0.2

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    playerLayer.frame = view.frame

    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player?.play()
    print("222")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.player?.play()
    }
}
}
```

AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    print("000")
    let ll: ViewController = ViewController()
    ll.test()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.


}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}
```

Comment: Try to put pause-action in "willResignActive" and play-action in "didBecomeActive".

Comment: You are creating a new instance of view controller not getting the existing one. thats why nothing is happening. You could register for appWillEnterForeground notification in your view controller and resume video playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` `UIApplicationWillResignActive` in Your `ViewController` as -

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBecomeActive), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appResignActive), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

@objc func appBecomeActive() {
   player.play()//Play video
}

@objc func appResignActive() {
    player.pause()//pause video
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622953-didbecomeactivenotification

Answer (score 1):

You can creating new instance in AppDelgate method However this is not good way to implement it.

In your `ViewController` class.  You can add observers that will be notify you and you can perform any action

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: .main) {[weak self] (noti) in
    guard let strongSelf = self  else {return }

   // DO here whatever you want 
}
```

it will be called when you app become active.